# How to get a BufferedImage from a Component in java?

Tags: java, components, bufferedimage

I know how to get a BufferedImage from JComponent, but how to get a BufferedImage from a Component in java ? The emphasis here is an object of the "Component" type rather than JComponent.

I tried the following method, but it return an all black image, what's wrong with it ?

```
  public static BufferedImage Get_Component_Image(Component myComponent,Rectangle region) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(myComponent.getWidth(), myComponent.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    myComponent.paint(g);
    g.dispose();
    return img;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get a BufferedImage from JComponent"?

Comment: Check out my new answer. Now it works. (Tested)

Answer (score 8):

`Component` has a method `paint(Graphics)`. That method will paint itself on the passed graphics. This is what we are going to use to create the `BufferedImage`, because BufferedImage has the handy method `getGraphics()`. That returns a `Graphics`-object which you can use to draw on the `BufferedImage`.

**UPDATE:** But we have to pre-configure the graphics for the paint method. That's what I found about the AWT Component rendering at [java.sun.com](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/):

> When AWT invokes this method, the
>   Graphics object parameter is
>   pre-configured with the appropriate
>   state for drawing on this particular
>   component:
>
> - The Graphics object's color is set to the component's foreground property.
> - The Graphics object's font is set to the component's font property.
> - The Graphics object's translation is set such that the coordinate (0,0) represents the upper left corner of the component.
> - The Graphics object's clip rectangle is set to the area of the component that is in need of repainting.

So, this is our resulting method:

```
public static BufferedImage componentToImage(Component component, Rectangle region) throws IOException
{
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(component.getForeground());
    g.setFont(component.getFont());
    component.paintAll(g);
    if (region == null)
    {
        region = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }
    return img.getSubimage(region.x, region.y, region.width, region.height);
}
```

Comment: How is this different from how you would do it for a `Component`? I think the question needs some clarification.

Comment: I tries it, still didn't work, maybe because the Component I passed to it is a WebBrowser object from JDIC, it's a non light weight Component, as I mentioned in my other question, do you know how to make it work ? Someone suggested I use CellRenderPane, but I don't know how to use it in my case, any sample code ?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I don't think this is an excellent answer. Creating a `BufferedImage` with fixed attributes may mean that its processing is much slower than necessary. Also, while the Q asks for a `BufferedImage`, changes are that an `Image` is enough. Why not simply use `Component.createImage()`?

Comment: This worked for me, although I may have been a bit smarter in obtaining a subregion.
img = new BufferedImage(region.width,region.height,...);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
g.translate(-region.x,-region.y);
component.paintAll(g);

I do believe Java optimises rendering based on clipping bounds, which should be the size of the image; it at least skips the getSubimage step if not.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [`Component.paintAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paintAll%28java.awt.Graphics%29).

You could also pass a reference to a Graphics object (coming from your buffered image) to [`SwingUtilities.paintComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics,%20java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Container,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: I'm with you that the intention of the Q has not been clarified. It would have been nice if you had mentioned the particular use case for which your answer is suitable.